# Express response undefined in promise

Tags: javascript, express, q

I use promises when setting up responses. My code looks something like this:

```
app.get("/api/assignment/user", getUserByUsername);

function getUserByUsername (req, res) {
    var username = req.query.username;
    model.findUserByUsername(username)
        .then(defaultJsonResponse(res), notFound(res));
}

function defaultJsonResponse(res) {
  return function(nObj) { defaultJsonResponse(nObj, res)};
}

function defaultJsonResponse(njson, res) {
    if(njson) res.json(njson);
    else notFound(res, "error");
}
```

When I run `getUserByUsername` method I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined`.
I'm having trouble understanding why the response is `undefined` in `defaultJsonResponse(njson, res)`

Comment: You must pass a callback to `then`, not the result of your function call. Wrap them in function expressions.

Comment: Why do you have function defaultJsonResponse defined twice? You are also missing the brackets after your if/else statement.

Comment: @user2263572, no need for brackets there. Are you sure you're getting a response? If yes, can you provide the JSON?

Comment: @Bergi `defaultJsonResponse(res)` returns a callback that just needs the result of the promise. @Filipe, the problem isn't that the response is returning undefined the problem is that when i reach the line `if(njson) res.json(njson);` the `res` argument is undefined. Also note that `notFound(res)` has a similar structure to `defaultJsonResponse(res)` where it returns a callback.

Comment: @laazer: Oh my, I'm blind. Of course it should. Your actual problem is that you've got two functions that go by the same name `defaultJsonResponse`, and the second overwrites the first - ending up in the situtation that you call the second without a `res`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as @Bergi said in the comment above, which is my lack of understanding about JavaScript function overloading. Problem was fixed by just giving the methods 2 different names.